# VUE: Error `Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'path' in undefined`; infinite loop; did check similiar question on Stackoverflow. github,web below

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

This is just my demo for learning purpose you can look at my full code at github: `https://github.com/tNhanDerivative/nhanStore_frontEnd` and my domain: vuestore.nhan-thenoobmaster.com
I don't see this error at my local machine but when I deploy my app on server. This happen. When I try to serve `npm run serve` these Error also does not appear. Only appear when I serve built file `dist/` from my server

```
Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'path' in undefined
    at Object.j [as resolve] (vue-router.mjs:3015:13)
    at w.fn (vue-router.mjs:2157:41)
    at w.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:190:25)
    at get value [as value] (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1171:39)
    at w.fn (vue-router.mjs:2159:35)
    at w.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:190:25)
    at get value [as value] (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1171:39)
    at w.fn (vue-router.mjs:2184:60)
    at w.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:190:25)
    at get value [as value] (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:1171:39)
```

Here is my router/index.js file. I have tried change `history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL)` to `history: createWebHistory()`. It does nothing
I also checked all the router-link all has `to` property

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

import store from '../store'

import HomeView from '../views/HomeView.vue'


import ProductView from '../views/ProductView.vue'
import CategoryView from '../views/CategoryView.vue'
import SearchView from '../views/SearchView.vue'
import CartView from '../views/CartView.vue'
import SignUpView from '../views/SignUpView.vue'
import LogInView from '../views/LogInView.vue'
import MyAccountView from '../views/MyAccountView.vue'
import CheckoutView from '../views/CheckoutView.vue'
import SuccessView from '../views/SuccessView.vue'



  const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: HomeView
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'AboutView',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/AboutView.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/sign-up',
    name: 'SignUp',
    component: SignUpView
  },
  {
    path: '/log-in',
    name: 'LogIn',
    component: LogInView
  },
  {
    path: '/my-account',
    name: 'MyAccount',
    component: MyAccountView,
    meta: {
        requireLogin: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/search',
    name: 'Search',
    component: SearchView
  },
  {
    path: '/cart',
    name: 'Cart',
    component: CartView
  },
  {
    path: '/cart/success',
    name: 'SuccessView',
    component: SuccessView
  },
  {
    path: '/cart/checkout',
    name: 'CheckoutView',
    component: CheckoutView,
    meta: {
        requireLogin: true
    }
  },
  {
    path: '/:category_slug/:product_slug',
    name: 'Product',
    component: ProductView
  },
  {
    path: '/:category_slug',
    name: 'Category',
    component: CategoryView
  }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requireLogin) && !store.state.isAuthenticated) {
    next({ name: 'LogIn', query: { to: to.path } });
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

export default router
```

Also for some reason it create an infinite loop for component `ProductBox` use inside HomView.vue.
[image]
You can see inside HomeView.vue the method `getLatestProducts()` hook `mounted` make an axios api call, updated `latestProducts` data and cause `ProductBox` to rerender.

I have tried different hook for Axios call beforeCreated() and created(). It doesn't work.
This is where I use the component
`HomeView.vue`

```js
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <section class="hero is-medium is-dark mb-6">
        <div class="hero-body has-text-centered">
            <p class="title mb-6">
                Welcome to NoobStore
            </p>
            <p class="subtitle">
                The most honest store online don't sell you anything
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <div class="columns is-multiline">
      <div class="column is-12">
          <h2 class="is-size-2 has-text-centered">Latest products</h2>
      </div>

      <ProductBox 
        v-for="product in latestProducts"
        v-bind:key="product.id"
        v-bind:product="product" />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

import ProductBox from '@/components/ProductBox'

export default {
  name: 'HomeView',
  data() {
    return {
      latestProducts: []
    }
  },
  components: {
    ProductBox
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getLatestProducts()

    document.title = 'Nhan`s Store | Vuejs demo'
  },
  methods: {
    async getLatestProducts() {
      this.$store.commit('setIsLoading', true)
      try {
        const res = await axios.get('/api/v1/latest-products/')
        this.latestProducts = res.data
      } catch(error) {
      console.log(error)
      }

      this.$store.commit('setIsLoading', false)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

check your api response, not expected. you got an html page not json

Comment: Thank you for answer my question. It make sense. I did fix my api response to json but the front end error is still there.

Comment: https://vuestore.nhan-thenoobmaster.com/apistrore.nhan-thenoobmaster.com/api/v1/latest-products/   still response with html

Comment: Btw, someone down vote my question for some reason. Can you upvote this question up I really need to fix this.